# Querying custom parse.com class returns null

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am currently developing an android application that uses Parse, and have created a custom Parse data class that holds some user data. However, querying this class always returns null or 0 when trying to retrieve data from one of the columns. This also happens if I try to query any of custom columns that I have made in the Parse User class. In addition, I have checked on the Parse data browser, and according to that, the data should be there.

Here is my code. I am using an application class to initialize Parse.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
String user_id;
String number_of_coins;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final View main = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);

    sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("My_Preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    user_id = sharedpreferences.getString("user_id", "");
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("User_Data");
    query.whereEqualTo("createdBy", ParseUser.getCurrentUser.getUsername);
    query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                number_of_coins = object.getNumber("coins").toString();
            } else {

            }
        }
    });

    ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
    bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#34495e")));
    bar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    bar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    bar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
    bar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    bar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    ActionBar.LayoutParams layout = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    View actionbar_view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.action_bar, null);
    ImageView settings_button = (ImageView) actionbar_view.findViewById(R.id.settings_button);
    settings_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Settings.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    TextView coins = (TextView) actionbar_view.findViewById(R.id.coins);
    coins.setText(String.valueOf(number_of_coins));
    bar.setCustomView(actionbar_view, layout);
    }
}
```

By the way, I am using Android Studio 1.2.1.1 and Parse 1.9.1

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just offering things that might work for you, don't know if these are definitive right answers.

Try querying by just the currentuser to see if you get something back. Also, it seems like you might have been missing the "()" at the end of getCurrentUser.

```
query.whereEqualTo("createdBy", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
```

This next option has worked for me in the past randomly.

```
number_of_coins = String.valueOf(object.get("coins"));
```